# How to use ABTasty's Flagship SDK for experimentation in .net 6 API with a generic approach?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, google-experiments, featuretoggle

I'm exploring ABTasty's flagship SDK for .Net 6 web api but it doesn't have samples of integration into .net 6 web api. When I googled, the resources are none for .net. If anyone used it before, request your help.

[Flagship .net SDK resource](https://docs.developers.flagship.io/docs/net-v30x#getting-started)

As of now, in Program.cs I've directly as per the reference link but I need a generic approach so I dependency inject a service having flagship reference. Could you please help?

```
// Use the Flagship package
using Flagship.Main;
// ...

Fs.Start("ENV_ID", "API_KEY");
```

Thanks in Advance